# Not able to apt-get install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently uninstalled Microsoft teams from my Ubuntu . After that whenever I install any other application I get the below message - I am not a Unix expert , any help here will largely be appreciated.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teams : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried the below command but there is no success.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

I tried the below command

```
sudo apt-get install --dry-run
```

and the o/p was -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 teams : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.19.12) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

No matter whatever I try to install, I get the same message.

I am using Ubuntu 16

As suggested I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and got the below output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data gimp-help-common gimp-help-en gyp javascript-common libamd2.4.1 libappindicator1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1
  libcholmod3.0.6 libevent-core-2.0-5 libgegl-0.3-0 libgimp2.0 libindicator7 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore
  libsdl1.2debian libssl-dev libssl-doc libumfpack5.7.1 libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.15.0-122 linux-headers-4.15.0-122-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-123 linux-headers-4.15.0-123-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-126 linux-headers-4.15.0-126-generic linux-image-4.15.0-122-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-123-generic linux-image-4.15.0-126-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-122-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-123-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-126-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-122-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-123-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-126-generic mypaint-data python-cairo python-gi python-gi-cairo python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-numpy
  python-pkg-resources snapd-login-service ubuntu-advantage-tools zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  teams
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 297 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 369322 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing teams (1.4.00.13653) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`? How exactly did you uninstall Teams?

Comment: I am not so great in linux , I used apt-get remove teams and then apt-get purge teams. However, my software center still says that Teams is still present in the system. When I try to launch it , it crashes. It looks like Teams  did not uninstall properly

Comment: That's what it looks like, yes. Did you try the command I suggested? If yes, please post the output. it's best not to add new info in comments, but edit the question instead so relevant details are available without digging them up from comment threads.

Comment: Added , please check

Comment: `The following packages will be REMOVED: teams` Looks like that did it :-) If you check it now in software center, it shouldn't show up as installed either.